# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid. PG Error

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to find a project from `Project` model using `Project.find(id)` but it is giving me `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` error

Full trace-

```
 PG::Error: ERROR: prepared statement "a1" already exists : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_class c LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace WHERE c.relkind in ('v','r') AND c.relname = $1 AND n.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1180:in `prepare'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1180:in `prepare_statement'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1144:in `exec_cache'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-     3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:664:in `block in exec_query'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:662:in `exec_query'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:797:in `table_exists?'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:30:in `table_exists?'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `table_exists?'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:75:in `get_primary_key'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:60:in `reset_primary_key'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:49:in `primary_key'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:230:in `block in columns'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `map'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:237:in `columns_hash'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:7:in `columns_hash'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:330:in `find_one'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:311:in `find_with_ids'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@submit_contactpl/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find'
/home/deploy/submit_contactpl/app/workers/php_worker.rb:5:in `perform'
```

Line 5 of `php_worker` is

```
 project = Project.find(project_id)
```

What might be the issue? Could you shade some light on it. What might be the possible solution

Answer (score 31, accepted):

all it needed was

```
 task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  #ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'

  Resque.before_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }
 end
```

in your `resque.rake` file

Comment: Shouldn't this one go into config/initializers/resque.rb instead, so that it is active everytime resque forks?

Comment: What is this doing, exactly? And why do we have to do it? Is it fixed in future versions of Resque or Rails (wherever the bug is living)?

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug somewhere in your Ruby stack.

It's trying to prepare a statement called "a1" which is examining table/view definitions (presumably for your "project" table). It finds out a prepared statement with the same name already exists and spits out an error. The query it is trying to prepare is fine - it returns a count of how many tables have a given name.

Either it's not tracking its prepared statements properly or it thinks it's deleted one and hasn't really. I'd update rails & activerecord and check for bug reports.